# How to match a list against a regular expression in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a list as below:

```
list1 = ["README.md", "test1.txt", "/desktop/openmpi.txt"]
```

I want to filter out all the file with `.md` and `.txt` extensions from this list and return me the result as boolean. So, if this list contains any `.md` or `.txt` files then return me true or if not then false.

I was trying the matcher class implementation but it did not work. I am not sure as to how can I do that with a list in one go.

My expected result is:

1. `True`: If the list contains any `.md` or `.txt` files.
2. `False`: If list does not contain any `.md` or `.txt` files.

Comment: Please also add the code you have tried and add how it failed.  So others can improve on it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use [`any`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_manipulating_lists) to see if there is an item in the list that matches a `/(?i)\.(?:md|txt)$/` regex:

```
def list1= ["README.md", "test1.txt","/desktop/openmpi.txt"]
print(list1.any { it =~ /(?i)\.(?:md|txt)$/ } )
```

Returns `true`.

See the [Groovy demo online](https://ideone.com/aBhHls).

The `(?i)\.(?:md|txt)$` regex matches

- `(?i)` - turning case insensitivity on
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:md|txt)` -  a non-capturing group matching either `md` or `txt`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: But another scenario is ,that if I have any other files apart from these two extensions like .sh or .mp3 then I want to return "false" in that case. Which means I want to return true only if this list has only .md and .txt files and nothing else.

Comment: @HemantKumar Then use `.every` instead of `.any`. Please read [1.4.1. Filtering and searching](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#List-Filtering).